# Результат поиска

Tags: php, get, search

Доброго времени суток.
Я реализовал поисковик в торговой площадке и результат должен быть такой что человек вбивает в поисковик название одежды, а результатом он получает магазин в которой есть эта вещь
и у меня появился такой вопрос:
поисковик нормально работает но когда есть 2 или более совпадений из одного и того же магазина, то появляется 2 одинаковых магазина. Не могу написать условие чтобы если в результате 2 магазина под одним id то объеденить их или 2 просто не показывать думаю что мой вопрос понятен)

```
if (isset($_GET['result'])) {
            $searchList = Main::getResultSearch($_GET['result']);
            foreach ($searchList as $search) {
                $shop = Main::getShopListBy($search['id_shop']);
                $shopid = $shop['id'];
                echo "<div class='content-block'>";
                echo "<a href='/center/shop/$shopid'><img src='" . Main::getShopLogo($shopid) ."'></a>";
                echo "<p>Время работы " . $shop['time'] . "</p>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
        }
```

Запрос к БД:

```
$db = Db::getConnection();
        $result = $db->query("SELECT name, id_shop FROM product WHERE name LIKE '%$text%' ORDER BY name");
        $i = 0;
        $searchList = array();
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $searchList[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
            $searchList[$i]['id_shop'] = $row['id_shop'];
            $i++;
        }
        return $searchList;
```

Comment: Забыли код метода, который осуществляет доступ к данным.

Comment: допишите в вашем SQL, ' GROUP BY id " и будет ваш счастье

Comment: А теперь найдите кнопку "править" под вопросом и перенесите контент из комментария в тело вопроса. Потом прочтите хотя бы [tour].

Comment: Broouzer King проблема решена спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

допишите в вашем SQL, ' GROUP BY id "